# why maven-compiler-plugin exclude disable

Tags: java, maven

```
             <plugin>
                 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                 <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                 <configuration>
                     <excludes>
                         <exclude>**/Application.java</exclude>
                     </excludes>
                 </configuration>
             </plugin>
```

this is my pom.xml , maven-compiler-plugin.version is 3.8.1 .

but i see the Applciation.class still in my jar package by maven

[image]

Comment: That's not where you should look. Check the `target` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at the wrong location. From what I see in the screenshot, you've found some `Application` file from the `External Libraries`. What the `maven-compiler-plugin` does is to generate the `target` folder. That's where the class file should be excluded from. Check the existence of the file class under:

```
target/classes/...
```

And don't forget to run `mvn clean install` before (with emphasis on **clean** - this will wipe out your `target` folder)

Comment: thanks for your answer,my colleague deploy the jar but i found this problem.I also have some misunderstanding about maven concept , 'mvn install' belong to maven default lifecycle , and 'mvn clean ' belong to clean lifecycle . i think 'install' will auto run 'clean' before , now I read "Maven Introduction to the Build Lifecycle" and there is a word said "These lifecycle phases (plus the other lifecycle phases not shown here) are executed sequentially to complete the default lifecycle. "

maybe he build the project with IDE that ignore the POM compile conf and then 'mvn deploy' directly.

Comment: No `install` lifecyle will not contain a clean...except you have bound something yourself....(Hopefully not!)

Answer (score 0):

In a project, I had to do a similar thing, due I need to exclude the `module-info.java`. I resolved using this configuration:

```xml
 <plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>  
   <executions>
     <execution>
       <id>default-compile</id>
       <configuration>
         <excludes>
           <exclude>**/module-info.java</exclude>
         </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

If you want the entire project you can get it from [GitHub](https://github.com/xcesco/reversi/blob/master/reversi-core/pom.xml). I hope this helps.